# How do i change the navigation bar button item state according to tableview row delete

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my navigation bar i have a `rightBarButtonItem` which needs to change the title according to `tableView` row delete.

```
editItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: Strings.CallHistory.edit, style: .plain, target: Selector, action: Selector{ [weak self] _ in

            self?.editAction()

        })

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.viewModel.history.count == 0 ? nil : editItem
```

where editItem has two title as follows **Edit** and **Done**

under `tableViewDelegates`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.editAction()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {

        self.editAction()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {

            viewModel.deleteFromHistory(indexPath: indexPath, completion: { [weak self] in

                self?.viewModel.history.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self?.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

                if self?.viewModel.history.count == 0 {
                    self?.editAction()
                    self?.setBackgroundView()
                }
            })

        }

    }
```

And so the editAction does the title change and tableView editing mode for me:

```
func editAction() {
        self.editMode = !editMode
        self.setEditing(editMode, animated: true)
        changeNavBarStatus()
    }

    func changeNavBarStatus() {
        if self.viewModel.getCount() != 0 {
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = editMode ? Strings.CallHistory.done : Strings.CallHistory.edit
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editMode ? self.clearItem : nil
        }
        else {

            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        }

    }
```

where `editMode` is the boolean to maintain the status when or when not to change the editing mode.

But the thing is when i swipe my row from right to left it shows the delete button and the same time i want to close the editing by pressing done button of the navigation bar rather than deleting it which won't change the title as the line

```
self.setEditing(editMode, animated: true)
```

calls the following method twice and eventually undo the title change:

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?)
```

So how should i implement it such a way that i wouldn't face this scenario.

Comment: make your `editItem` a class var and modify the var instead of `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title`

Comment: And how that would help? @thorb65

Answer (score 0):

Well i have made it work. I have made a few adjustments to accomplish it.

under the method `didEndEditingRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {

        self.setEditing(editMode, animated: true)
    }
```

Made the `editMode` computed property under which implemented `didSet`:

```
var editMode: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            changeNavBarStatus()
        }
    }
```

And under `editAction`:

```
func editAction() {
        self.editMode = !editMode
        self.setEditing(editMode, animated: true)
    }
```